# Blazor WASM File Getting Error on SSL Domain

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, cloudflare

Blazor WASM application gives error. It does not get files that are required for WASM initial load. In request of files there is an alert that says `Provisional headers are shown.`.

To Deploy Blazor WASM application using CloudFlare in the middle.
[Structure of Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Paw0F.png)

Blazor WASM runs on IIS. Binding setting are as follows.
[IIS Binding settings](https://imgur.com/a/sAcARcY)

Published project file structure as follows.
[Published File Stucture](https://imgur.com/a/NnXsSps)

IIS URL Rewrite configured as follow.
[URL Rewrite View on IIS](https://imgur.com/a/Bkvv0v9)

Web.config file Content that contains URL Rewrite configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

On CloudFlare section SSL/TLS encryption mode is selected as **Flexible**.
[CloudFlare SSL Mode](https://imgur.com/a/cFGSD9C)

CloudFlare Record settings are as follows.
[Record Settings](https://imgur.com/a/NTIOj1H)

After publishing, file getting error is shown on  dev tools network screen as follows
[Network Screen File Error](https://imgur.com/a/0sGvwiR)

All File have same error. Error is as follows.
[File Error](https://imgur.com/a/NrUJaLM)

In addition above configuration, Blazor WASM was published from both **Client** and **Host**.
When SSL/TLS is in use, it gives error both of **Client** and **Host** based publish. There is no error on **Http** requests.

What do i missing while publishing? What should i do?